# Core Animation and Anti Aliased Fonts on the Mac

Tags: cocoa, xcode, macos, interface-builder, core-animation

I'm trying to create a view that is backed by a Core Animation layer. However, when I enable the layer, my labels start to look slightly jagged. I've attached a demonstration of difference:

[image: Excluding Core Animation Layer]
[image: Including Core Animation Layer]

I know it is subtle, but it is driving me crazy (especially for smaller fonts). Any way I can get the Core Animation layer labels to be anti-aliased?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nitpick: the Core Animation layer is anti-aliased, but at a lower quality – it doesn’t use sub-pixel anti-aliasing. The reason for this is that sub-pixel anti-aliasing requires per-channel blending, which can’t be done cheaply with hardware compositing.

The example linked from [here](http://lists.apple.com/archives/Cocoa-dev/2009/Jan/msg02300.html) demonstrates various ways of working around this problem.

Comment: Ah I have the same problem but Apple just took down their list archives. Can anyone help me out? In my project one xib looks fine but the other is jagged.

Comment: still don't know how to fix it :/